# How to add options uses pointer this

Tags: jquery

In function $( window ).ready(function(){} I must initialize depending on the value. 
But i don't know, how can i put a new option to the current select.

```
 $("select[name=status] > option").each(function() {
     a = this;
     $(this).append(new Option('kaka', 'loko');
  });
```

thank you for help.

Comment: `$(window).ready()` is an anti-pattern. The `ready` method applies to the document, not the window.

Comment: You want to add more options to the select element?

Comment: to the current select i would insert a new option

Answer (score 2):

You can simple:

```js
$("<option/>",{
    text: "kaka",
    value: "loco"
    
}).appendTo("select[name=status]");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="status"></select>
```

For your case to check the value of `option`:

```js
$("select[name=status] > option").each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "2") {
        $("<option/>", {
            text: "kaka",
            value: "loco"
        }).insertAfter($(this));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="status">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I would like to thank you all for your help. Now all is working correct. once again thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name=status]').each(function() {
        $(this).append('<option value="kaka">loko</option>');
    });
});
```

As mentioned by Frédéric Hamidi

> $(window).ready() is an anti-pattern. The ready method applies to the
>   document, not the window

So the `ready` event is only fired on the `document`

Comment: exactly, this is what i want to achieve. Last thing, how can i get value from select. I try $(this).find('select').text(), but this not working :(